# Error while Adding google gms services for flutter android project and tired of searching answers

Tags: flutter, android-gradle-plugin, google-cloud-firestore, gradlew, flutter-dependencies

```
* Error running Gradle:
ProcessException: Process "C:\Users\aarav\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_firestoreapp\android\gradlew.bat" exited abnormally:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v4:27.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/appcompat-v4/27/appcompat-v4-27.pom
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/appcompat-v4/27/appcompat-v4-27.jar
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v4/27/appcompat-v4-27.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v4/27/appcompat-v4-27.jar
     Required by:
         project :

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6s
  Command: C:\Users\aarav\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_firestoreapp\android\gradlew.bat app:properties

Finished with error: Please review your Gradle project setup in the android/ folder.
```

I tried offline gradles of all versions.

App-gradle :

```
    dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.1.1'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Project-gradle :

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
        classpath 'com.android.support:appcompat-v4:27'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54603897/flutter-fail-to-run-app-on-device-import-androidx-annotation-nullable/54605272#54605272

Answer (score 0):

Migrate to AndroidX (see also [Flutter fail to run app on device import androidx.annotation.Nullable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54603897/flutter-fail-to-run-app-on-device-import-androidx-annotation-nullable/54605272#54605272)) and use the latest plugin versions,
or ensure that you use plugin versions that don't yet depend on AndroidX.

This issue contains more details https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27128