# How to connect caller and reciever using Twilio API in Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, twilio, voip

I just setup Twilio API in my flutter project and I've been able to make outbound calls to international phone numbers, but i have a problem and i hope someone can point me in the right direction. When a call is sent from my flutter app and it successfully registers as a call on the recievers's phone, how do i connect my flutter app to engage in a live call with recipient after call is accepted?

Here's the code that performs API call below

```
Future<http.Response> accessTwilioAPI() async {
    http.Response response = await http.post(
      Uri.https("api.twilio.com",
          "/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACCOUNT_SID_GOES_HERE/Calls/.json"),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Authorization': 'Basic ' +
            toAuthCredentials("ACCOUNT_SID_GOES_HERE",
                "AUTH_TOKEN_GOES_HERE")
      },
      body: {
        //body goes here

        "From": "TWILIO_NUMBER",
        "To": "RECIPIENT",
        "Url":
            "TWIML_BIN_URL",
        "duration": "30",
      },
    );

    print(response.body);
  }
```

UPDATE
So i've been able to establish a two way communication but its not exactly what i want yet. what i did was to place a call first to my phone number (not twilio phone number) then i used the  Dial TwiML verb to connect call to another person, it works but the limitation of this approach is that caller would have to recieve a call before it is routed to reciever.

Comment: What are you using in your Flutter app to make the outbound calls? Can you share the code you are using?

Comment: I'll update my question to show the API call

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can make calls directly from native mobile applications using the [Twilio Voice SDK](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/sdks). There are SDKs available for iOS, Android and JavaScript. The Voice SDK allows you to make and receive calls from within your application and can hook into native UI, like CallKit on iOS.

In terms of Flutter, you can either integrate the platform yourself (this [Stack Overflow answer has a description of how to do so in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65960245/28376)) or check out the community built Flutter wrappers for the native SDKs. There's [`flutter_twilio_voice`](https://github.com/GoHighLevel/flutter_twilio_voice) or [`flutter_voice`](https://github.com/diegogarciar/twilio_voice).

---

In response to the code you have so far, this is a bad idea for a few reasons. Firstly, as you've discovered, the calls are made outside of the context of the application. Secondly, making API requests from within the application means that your application will contain or expose your API credentials. If a malicious user were to decompile the app, they could extract your credentials and abuse your account.

Comment: oh wow.. thanks for the help, i will go through this links and revert

Comment: I have been able to set up the twilio_voice package in my app and i can place a call now but the call immediately ends with a voice response that says"an application error has occured" i checked my Twilio console and noticed the error log has 11200 - HTTP retrieval error, i figured this error is connected to the url i assigned to the Twiml app, i used the default url that was provided in the Android Quickstart Tutorial (https://my-quickstart-dev.twil.io/make-call) Am i supposed to provide my own URL? if yes, how do i do that?

Comment: That URL points to a 404. Did you follow the instructions to deploy the QuickStart application?

Comment: Yeah.. i did, but i skpped the step that is supposed to set Twilio environment variables using Twilio serverless Plugin because I am using Firebase Environment Variables, is that the issue?

Comment: To start with it would likely be best to complete the full instructions and use the URL you get at the end. Once you understand how it works you can then translate to Firebase or wherever you want to host it.

Comment: Ok.. just to be sure, you mean I'm supposed to get a url after initiating the twilio serverless:deploy command?

Comment: Yes, that command will print out the URL of your functions when it completes.